# Reuse Angular Component multiple times in a loop with complex object input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Every approach I found wouldn't work so far.

I´m iterating trough video-objects...

```
export class video{
    constructor(
        public videoId: number,
        public sellerID: number,
        public title: string,
        public description: string,
        public price: number,
        public url,
        public votingPositive: number,
        public votingNegative: number,
        public views: number,
        public date: Date,
        public status: number,
        public previewImages: string[],
        public actors: string[],
        public genres: string[]) {}
}
```

...in the parent-component:

```
<div class="content-right">
  <app-video-list-item *ngFor="let videoItem of videos" [videoElement]="videoItem"></app-video-list-item>
</div>
```

My child component has the @Input() decorator:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-video-list-item',
    templateUrl: './video-list-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./video-list-item.component.css']
})
export class VideoListItemComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input('videoElement') videoItem:video;
...
```

this is the child-html:

```
<div class="item-wrapper">

    <div class="video-wrapper">
        <video controls height="200" id="video" src="{{videoItem.url}}"></video>
    </div>

    <div class="item-info-wrapper">
        <p class="item-text">{{videoItem.title}}</p><br>
        <p class="item-text">Upload date: {{videoItem.date.toLocaleDateString()}}</p><br>
        <p class="item-text">Price: {{videoItem.price}}$</p><br>
        <p class="item-text">Genres: {{getGenresAsSingleText()}}</p>
        <p class="item-text">Actors: {{getActorsAsSingleText()}}</p>

        <div class="item-action-wrapper">
            <button (click)="showDeleteModal()" class="item-action-button delete-icon"></button>
            <button (click)="editVideoItem()" class="item-action-button edit-icon"></button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

it shows the amount of child-views of the arrays content length but without any content. This is the result:

[image]

The title of the first video is shown but nothing more.

Has anyone else faced this problem?
All posts about this I found so far weren't helpful.

I checked the array before the iteration - its populated:

[image]

Comment: Did you check for errors in console?

Comment: yes, in the child component I logged the videoItem on every ngOnInit but only the first one was shown. I also checked the array before the iteration. it is populated.

Comment: Try this - `<div class="content-right">
 <div *ngFor="let videoItem of videos">
   <app-video-list-item  [videoElement]="videoItem"></app-video-list-item>
 </div>
</div>`

Comment: I already did. no change... :/

Comment: Put a {{videoItem.title}} after the ngFor but before the child component to see if the problem is in the child component or not

Comment: this works but only if I remove the child component tag..

Comment: Can you replicate this on a Sample StackBlitz and share it across so that someone could have a look?

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz url of your code? Looks like there is an issue in your child component.

Comment: Heres the editor link. as you see I add three videos with different titles.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdfggr

Comment: @NeoGER89 Well, in the stackblitz, you have hard coded the values in your class, thus all will have the same content.  Also, just a comment, do you really need to create instances of your class, you seem to not have any class specific methods, so couldn't just an interface suffice?

Comment: The hardcoded and the response from the backend in my app are about the same.. i use a class because I added a additional log method to the video class in my app.

Comment: Well if you do not use hardcoded values in your video class it works just as it should: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mp6yth?file=src/app/Overview/class.ts